# Unknown blob input data to layer 0 in caffe

Tags: caffe

I am getting following error while using my caffe prototxt:

```
F0329 17:37:40.771555 24587 insert_splits.cpp:35] Unknown blob input data to layer 0
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

The first 2 layers in my caffe prototxt is given below:

```
layers {
  name: "data"
  type: IMAGE_DATA
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  image_data_param {
    source: "train2.txt"
    batch_size: 100
    new_height: 28
    new_width: 28
    is_color: false
  }
}
layers {
  name: "conv1"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 3
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 8
    kernel_size: 9
    stride: 1
    weight_filler { type: "xavier" }
    bias_filler { type: "constant" }
  }
}
```

What could be the possible reason for the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

t seems like your `IMAGE_DATA` layer is only defined for `TRAIN` phase. Thus blobs `data` and `label` are not defined for `TEST` phase. I suspect you see no error when the solver builds the train phase net,  and only when test phase net is built then the error appears.