# Slicing an input data layer in caffe - unknown blob input

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to do pixel-wise classification with caffe, so need to provide a ground truth image the size of the input image. There is several ways of doing this, and I decided to set up my input as a **4-channel LMDB** (according to the 2nd point of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45181897/884412)). This requires me to add a `Slice` layer after my input, which is also outlined in the [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45181897/884412).

I keep getting `Unknown blob input data_lmdb to layer 0` as an error message (`data_lmdb` is supposed to be my very bottom input layer). I found that `unknown blob` (be it top or bottom) error is mostly caused by forgetting to define something in one of the TRAIN / TEST phases while defining it in the other (e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49560165/884412), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39888054/884412)). But, I am using a combination of `train.prototxt`, `inference.prototxt` and `solver.prototxt` files that I have previously used, just replacing the input layers from HD5 to LMDB (for a bit of practice), so everything should be defined.

Can anybody see why I am getting the `Unknown blob input data_lmdb to layer 0` error? From the train log files I can see that it crashes as soon as it reads the `train.prototxt` file (it doesn't even reach the `Creating layer` part).

My `prototxt` files are as follows:

`solver.prototxt`

```
net: "train.prototxt"       # Change this to the absolute path to your model file
test_initialization: false
test_iter: 1
test_interval: 1000000
base_lr: 0.01
lr_policy: "fixed"
gamma: 1.0
stepsize: 2000
display: 20
momentum: 0.9
max_iter: 10000
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 100
snapshot_prefix: "set_snapshot_name"    # Absolute path to output solver snapshots
solver_mode: GPU
```

`train.prototxt` (first two layers only; they are followed by a `LNR` normalization layer and then a `Convolution` layer):

```
name: "my_net"
layer {
  name: "data_lmdb"
  type: "Data"
  top: "slice_input"
  data_param {
    source: "data/train"
    batch_size: 4
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer{
  name: "slice_input"
  type: "Slice"
  bottom: "data_lmdb" # 4-channels = rgb+truth
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  slice_param {
    axis: 1
    slice_point: 3  
  }
}
```

The first few layer definitions in `inference.prototxt` are *identical* to `train.prototxt` (which shouldn't matter anyway as it is not used in training) except the following:

- in `data_lmdb` the source path is different (`data/test`)
- in `data_lmdb` layer uses `batch_size: 1`

Please do let me know if I need to include any more information or layers. I was trying to keep it brief, which didn't really work out in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message `Unknown blob input` points on non-existent blob that some layer wants to have as input. Your `slice_input` layer specified `data_lmdb` as input blob, but there is no such a blob in your network. Instead, you have a *layer* with such a name. Blob names are defined by the `top` field, which is `slice_input` in this case.

You shoud either change `top: "slice_input"` to `top: "data_lmdb"` in your `data_lmdb` layer, or use `bottom: "slice_input" # 4-channels = rgb+truth`.

However, for more clear naming I would offer you the following:

```
name: "my_net"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data_and_label"
  data_param {
    source: "data/train"
    batch_size: 4
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer{
  name: "slice_input"
  type: "Slice"
  bottom: "data_and_label" # 4-channels = rgb+truth
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  slice_param {
    axis: 1
    slice_point: 3  
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh this explains so much, thank you. Apparently I need to go and re-read some of the introductory materials for caffe; I wasn't aware that layers and the blobs they define are different; probably since people tend to name them the same.